# Silence Notifications from Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu, kde, notifications

I have Ubuntu One syncing my code folder. Every time a save is made (I save every other line), Ubuntu One displays a notification that it has synced changes.

Is there a way to make Ubuntu One be quiet?

Note that I am using KDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can silence the notifications.

On the Ubuntu One control panel, under devices, there is a tick box for "Show activity notifications". Just untick that.

There is a [screenshot here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36197/can-you-disable-notifications-on-ubuntu-one-sync).